# PHP switch statement (endswitch) gives Parse error for alternative syntax

Tags: php

I am getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '', expecting endswitch (T_ENDSWITCH) or case (T_CASE) or default (T_DEFAULT) in ...` with the following code

[myview.phtml](http://ideone.com/DqwG1q)

```
<?php switch ($oEx->getCode()): ?>

<?php default: ?>
Stuff

<?php endswitch; ?>
```

Whereas [this is OK](http://ideone.com/c8ZHMr)

```
<?php switch ($oEx->getCode()):

endswitch; ?>
```

**Why?** A work around is to add [a dummy-case as below](http://ideone.com/e9uHvv) before the closing tag but I can't see why this should be necessary.

```
<?php switch ($oEx->getCode()): case -9999: break; ?>

<?php default: ?>
Stuff

<?php endswitch; ?>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php):

> **Warning**
>   Any output (including whitespace) between a switch statement and the first case will result in a syntax error. For example, this is invalid:

```
<?php switch ($foo): ?>
    <?php case 1: ?>
    ...
<?php endswitch ?>
```

> Whereas this is valid, as the trailing newline after the switch statement is considered part of the closing ?> and hence nothing is output between the switch and case:

```
<?php switch ($foo): ?>
<?php case 1: ?>
    ...
<?php endswitch ?>
```

The issue isn't the ending PHP tag, it's the whitespace.  I think if you modified your original code as below, it should get rid of your syntax error:

```
<?php switch ($oEx->getCode()): ?>
<?php default: ?>
Stuff
<?php endswitch; ?>
```

Notice the only change made is removing the newline between your `switch` statement and the `default` case.

Comment: You are of course correct sir. Can't believe I missed that :P Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After you have a `switch` there's nothing in between beside a `default` or a `case`

```
<?php switch ($oEx->getCode()): ?>
//You can't have anything else here
<?php default: ?>
Stuff

<?php endswitch; ?>
```

So you have to place a default or a case just nest to switch without a new line or anything else :

```
<?php switch ($oEx->getCode()): ?>
<?php default: ?>
Stuff

<?php endswitch; ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
            <?php switch (1): 
                case 1:?>
                    <div>foo1</div>
            <?php break;?>
            <?php default:?>
                    <div>foo2</div>
        <?php endswitch; ?>
```

I try this code ,and his work